# Is there a way to disable ligatures in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

Is there a way to disable the display of ligatures in Outlook client?
For some reason, emails from certain recipients are hardly readable due to their use of ligatures like `st` and `ck`. The same emails viewed from the online client look normal.
Is there some way to disable the ligatures rendering?

Comment: I think it's due to the font. Moreover, I don't see any ligatures in your examples `st` & `ck`

Comment: @Toto because it's a text, not a picture. Howe you see them? If I copy the text it obviously copies without ligatures. It might be the font issue, but when I view the same email in the browser it doesn't have them. So supposedly it's possible to transparently disable them without messing with the fonts.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the fonts issue, you could try to change the font and check if this issue continues. When you view the same email in the browser it doesn't have them, It may be due to compatibility issues that the browser fails to display ligatures.

For more details: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/13484/use-advanced-font-ligatures-in-office-2010/

Comment: How would I change the font for single sender?

Comment: To narrow down this issue, try to ask the sender change the font and send a mail to you, then you check if it continues, you can do nothing in sender side.